# Meaning of various Shree Vishnu chinha

Tags: vishnu, padma-purana

I read the definitions of the Chinha of Shree Vishnu all over the print media by various scholars but no one has ever given a answer which is already not in print or discussion. Can someone explain from his own cosmic and spiritual connection with the Bhagwan himself.

Comment: Chinha as in Charan Chinha?